# UKHost4U and MySQL - How to connect?

Tags: mysql-connect

been waiting an hour to find out correct way to connect to mysql at UKHOST4U, thought someone on here may know?

Been using the following code, database, user & password are all setup correctly:

```
$hostn='localhost';
$dbn='cpanel1_dbname';
$passn='password';
$usern='cpanel1_usrname';
$dbh = @mysqli_connect($hostn, $usern, $passn, $dbn);
if(!$dbh)
    die('hmm that did not seem to work; please try another day..');
```

I have obvioulsy changed the actual values.

I have just moved to UKHost4U - Am I missing something?!

Comment: have you tried contacting their support team ?

Comment: been waiting an hour to find out correct way..

Comment: try changing $hostn='localhost'; to $hostn='localhost:3306';

Comment: nope that didnt work, I have tried a few diff possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contact them and 'then it worked' as per normal..